# LINQ - Wildcard on an int column in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, casting, linq-to-sql

I have a table that returns records from the database. The users have various dropdowns and input boxes where they can search specific results within columns. I have an input box that searches a column that takes an int and null values. If the user does not specify anything inside of the input box, I want to return all applicable records from that column.

Either the value of the classroom size input box is an integer, or it is set as a wildcard if the user does not specify. This is why I run into a cast issue.

The way I have it set it up now returns a 400 status if I do not specify an integer in the input box. Please let me know how I can accomplish my goal, thank you for your time!

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Models.tblClassrooms>

    <div>
    <form method="get" role="form" asp-controller="Classroom" asp-action="Index">
        <label>Class Size</label>
        <input type="search" value="@ViewData["sizeSearch"]" name="sizeSearch" />
        <input asp-controller="Classroom" asp-action="Search" value="Search" type="submit" />
    </form>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Search(string sizeSearch)
{
    ViewData["sizeSearch"] = sizeSearch;

    var query = from x in _db.tblClassrooms
                .Where(x => x.ID == 10)
                select x;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sizeSearch))
    {
        //set a variable equal to a 'wildcard'
        //this is where I run into a cast issue
    }

    //adding to the query above, search by that table, where the ID is 10,
    //furthermore, search by either the classroom size or the wildcard
    query = query.Where(x =>
    x.ClassSize.Equals(sizeSearch));

    return View("Index", await query.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());

}
```

Note: I am using ID = 10 for testing purposes. Please keep in mind that I have other values that I am also searching by.

Comment: Please show an example record of data, so we can see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your usage of the word 'wildcard' correctly, you could just omit the second where clause:

```cs
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sizeSearch))
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.ClassSize.Equals(sizeSearch));
}
```

This way, if nothing is passed into `sizeSearch`, you will not be filtering your query by it.

Comment: Why use `Equals` over `==`?

Comment: Just going with what the OP had.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean. The only problem with that is that if the user does not specify a value, then the Search action cannot happen. I get a 400 status (bad request). @Collen

Comment: That problem may be in your view. What does the rest of the form markup look like?

Comment: @Collen I added more relevant information about my view.

Comment: @Collen also, my wildcard I mean something like % in SQL. It will return all values from a column

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your 400 error in a test project. As far as the wildcard goes, omitting the `Where` clause will not filter by any value of `ClassSize`. For example, you would get the same results from `SELECT * FROM tblClassrooms` and `SELECT * FROM tblClassrooms WHERE ClassSize LIKE '%'`.